# ¿Como puedo imprimir toda la tabla con window.print() sin que se me corte?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, tablas

, resulta que necesito imprimir todos los registros de una tabla, lo hice con el metodo window.print(),me lo produce pero al ser muchos registros me lo corta por ejemplo al registro 25 hacia adelante ya me corta, y solo con un escalado se me ven los siguientes registros porque probablente no quepan en una hoja de oficio, como puedo hacer que los siguientes registros se ingresen en una siguiente hoja  y no todo en uno , o esto es de forma automatica? para evitar que se corte,  de antemano Muchas gracias!

Adjunto imagen de referencia
[image: IMagen1]

[image: Imagen 2]

[image: Imagen 3]

Código de boton window.print();

```html
                <button onclick="window.print()" class="btn btn-success btn-raised btn-xs">Imprimir</button>
```

Comment: Hola Luis, por favor edita tu pregunta y añade detalles necesarios como el código que estás utilizando, un screenshot de lo que esperas, un screenshot de los resultados obtenidos. Con la información que compartes será difícil ayudarte

Comment: @Arriel Gracias por responder Ariel!, Se produjo el cambio! Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Coloca tu tabla dentro de un Div con id "Impresion"

```
function printDiv(impresion) {
     var contenido= document.getElementById(impresion).innerHTML;
     var contenidoOriginal= document.body.innerHTML;
    


     document.body.innerHTML = contenido;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = contenidoOriginal;
}
```